# Why is MySQL using this index? Can I force it to use another?

Tags: mysql, index, explain

I have a query, and when I call `EXPLAIN` for it, it appears that my db is using an unhelpful index and ignoring a useful index.

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT id, full_name, agent_id, brand_id FROM `mytable`
WHERE (
    `mytable`.`brand_id` IN (21264)
    OR
    `mytable`.`agent_id` IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11)
    )
    AND (full_name IS NOT NULL AND full_name != '')
    AND (full_name LIKE '%kath%' OR id = 12 OR id = 0)   
    ORDER BY full_name ASC LIMIT 15
```

(That query was auto-generated, hence the strange parentheses.)

The table has a few inidices:

```
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name                               | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| mytable |          0 | PRIMARY                                |            1 | id          | A         |     1329001 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable |          1 | mytable_by_agent_id                    |            1 | agent_id    | A         |        9561 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable |          1 | mytable_by_brand                       |            1 | brand_id    | A         |        4598 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable |          1 | mytable_by_full_name                   |            1 | full_name   | A         |     1329001 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE          |         |               |
| mytable |          1 | index_mytable_on_brand_id_and_agent_id |            1 | brand_id    | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable |          1 | index_mytable_on_brand_id_and_agent_id |            2 | agent_id    | A         |        1205 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

And I 'd expect the query to make use of `index_mytable_on_brand_id_and_agent_id`, but instead, `EXPLAIN` reveals that it's using `mytable_by_full_name`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: consumers
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,mytable_by_agent_id,mytable_by_brand,mytable_by_full_name,index_mytable_on_brand_id_and_agent_id
          key: mytable_by_full_name
      key_len: 258
          ref: NULL
         rows: 811112
        Extra: Using where
```

How can I get this to use the other index? Why did it choose an index which won't help (because of the `%` at the start of the `LIKE`)?

Comment: The index you want it to use won't help either, because of `OR mytable.agent_id IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11)`. There probably isn't a single index that will be useful for the assortment of criteria you throw at it.

Comment: @Akina thanks for that correction. I've updated indices' names above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No index will help with the `WHERE` clause -- part has `OR`, part has `LIKE` with an initial wild card.

So, the only hope for optimizing is to work on the `ORDER BY`.  However, that is risky -- it might finish after looking at 15 rows, or it might look at the entire table without finding 15 rows.  (Or some amount in between).

A single `OR` can usually be turned into `UNION` to good advantage.  But 2 `ORs` is too messy to contemplate.